# Do I need wpa_suppliciant and wireless_tools if I use nmcli to connect to wifi?

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, wpa-supplicant, nmcli

I am installing Arch and the question comes in this simple command.

```
pacstrap /mnt ... networkmanager
```

I am using my laptop with wireless connection. After installing arch linux I am going to use `nmcli` to connect to wifi. Do I need to install **wpa_suppliciant** and **wireless_tools** or it'not necessary if you're using **nmcli**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to install wpa_suppliciant and wireless_tools or it'not necessary if you're using nmcli?

wireless_tools isn't required.

`nmcli` is used to configure [`wpa_supplicant`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wpa_supplicant). `wpa_supplicant` is necessary to connect to a protected WPA* wifi.

[iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd) (iNet wireless daemon)  is an alternative to wpasupplicant.

Answer (score 1):

wpa_supplicant is required by NetworkManager, but wireless_tools is not.

You don't have to explicitly install wpa_supplicant though, pacstrap will pull in NetworkManager's dependencies automatically.